# In my STS ,lombok Is not working . am using java language and os is windows

Tags: spring, lombok

How to solve the issue that I faced in my STS .the issue is lombok is not supporting in my STS .I already installed jar file in my sts folder .and i added dependency in my pom.xml .and the the libraries are getting in my project but cant create getters ,setters and builder method .and constructor also I cant getting in my Service layer
but still not working what to do .I Hope I get replay as soon as possible